# How to call Microsoft Graph from Azure Functions

Tags: azure-functions, microsoft-graph-api

I'm actually stuck trying to make Microsoft graph API calls inside an Azure Functions (with App Authentication Service enabled). My functions are running with javascript (node).

I can actually get some tokens from the `req.headers` (`x-ms-token-aad-id-token`, `x-ms-token-aad-access-token`, etc.).

I found [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-microsoft-graph#auth-token---javascript-example). The bindings are not working as the function get an `HTTP 404` when I try to call it (with the browser), right after I updated and saved the `functions.js` file.

I also tried to [call](https://graph.microsoft.com/me) manually, using the `x-ms-token-aad-id-token` token inside the request headers (`Authentication: Bearer xxx-token-xxx`), but get an error response:

> "Access token validation failure. Invalid audience."

I tried to use `@microsoft/microsoft-graph-client` and got the same message. Maybe it's a configuration problem between my functions and the aad app registration?

```js
const token = req.headers['x-ms-token-aad-id-token'];

try {
    const client = graph.Client.init({
        authProvider: (done) => {
            done(null, token);
        }
    });

    const user = await client.api('/me').get();
    context.log(user);
} catch(e) {
    context.log(e);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of issues here:

1. The URI  `https://graph.microsoft.com/me` isn't valid, it lacks a version number in the path. The root URI should be `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0`.
2. When authenticating using Client Credentials (i.e. without a user), there is no `/me`. The `/me/` segment is an alias for `/users/{id of the authenticated user from the token you passed me}`. Since you don't *have* an "authenticated user", `/me` translated to `/user/null` which, obviously, doesn't exist (`404`).
3. The `x-ms-token-aad-id-token` isn't an Access Token, it's an ID token. Furthermore, it was almost assuredly issued for the resource or scopes you want (`invalid audience`). Your function needs to retrieve the token for itself for the tenant you want, using the scopes you require.

You need to explicitly pass in the User Id or User Principal Name (aka UPN):

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/users/username@domain.onmicrosoft.com
```

Comment: Ok I think I got it ... I got an access token from https://login.microsoftonline.com/[tenant_id]/oauth2/v2.0/token and then I used the access token to call https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/[object_id]. But now I got the error : "Authorization_RequestDenied : Insufficient privileges to complete the operation.".

On my app registration / api permissions, I already have User.Read and User.ReadBasic.All granted

Comment: You need to register for `User.Read.All` and receive Admin Consent for the app id. `User.Read` and `User.ReadBasic.All` are Delegated, not Application scopes.